# Background of a LinearLayout disappears when inside a scrollview, depending on the height of the linearLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview, android-linearlayout

**SOLVED**
This problem was "solved" by debugging my app on a different tablet. The first tablet I used was a Samsung Tab 2 10.1. Now I'm using a Samsung Note 10.1 and it works fine. I would be happy to get some feedback from anyone encountering the same issue to know more about it.

**Post**
This is my first post on this forum. 
I'm developing a application for android and I'm facing a **challenging problem**. I haven't found any post related to this problem and as I have no clue how to solve it I decided to explain it here. 
Let say it's my Christmas gift for you ;)

Ok, here is what I do. Basically, I inflate a fragment with this xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical" >
            <LinearLayout style="@style/LayoutDetailsStep" >
                <TextView
                   style="@style/textkey"
                   android:text="Name:" />
                <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/name"
                   style="@style/editkey" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout style="@style/LayoutDetailsStep" >
                <TextView
                   style="@style/textkey"
                   android:text="Description:" />
                <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/description"
                   style="@style/editkey" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout style="@style/LayoutDetailsStep" >
                <TextView
                   style="@style/textkey"
                   android:text="SOP:" />
                <WebView
                   android:id="@+id/sop"
                   style="@style/editkey" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout style="@style/LayoutDetailsStep" >
                <TextView
                   style="@style/textkey"
                   android:text="Notes:" />
                <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/notes"
                   style="@style/editkey" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

So basically, my fragment is composed one ScrollView composed of 4 LinearLayouts containing each a TextView and a TextView/WebView. I apply a style *LayoutDetailsStep* to each LinearLayout which is this one:

```
 <style name="LayoutDetailsStep"  >
     <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
     <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
     <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/round_border</item>
     <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">20dp</item>
     <item name="android:layout_marginRight">20dp</item>
     <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
     <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
 </style>
```

The style contains a background *round_border* which is this one:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
        <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
```

When everything goes right, I have a nice pile of 4 LinearLayout with nice round borders. Everything is nice as long as the items inside the LinearLayout are small. It looks like this: [image when it's fine](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=204790Screenshot20121221094503.jpg).

The problems appear when an item is bigger that the size of the fragment itself. **When the height of the WebView/TextView (both are problematic) is bigger than the height of the Fragment, the background disappears**. It looks like this: [background has disappeared](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=857140Screenshot20121221094534.jpg)

In practice the TextViews are quite small and this problem doesn't happen with them. But I can display rather big WebViews, which causes the background to disappear, which means that there is no round border surrounding the LinearLayout of the WebView. 
**I insist that it's not specific to the WebView, if the TextView are large enough, I get the same issue.**

If anyone has any idea what is going on... I would be happy to read your suggestion :D

Gordak

Comment: When you post question, please use TAG android for everyone easy know that is android question. when you use android TAG, your question will be highlight for everyone has favorite in Android and you will be get answer quickly

Comment: Thank you. Apparently it also fixed the color of the text code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was fixed in 4.0.4.